# Test for multiple strings in a certain order

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to test for multiple strings in a certain order? Something like this:

```
if str.find(["who", "are", "you"], "who the heck are you") != -1:
    Print("I AM JOE")
```

Comment: You're pretty close. Just remember the find() function provides a positive integer value for the index. So if who is 5 and are is 9 then they are in order!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to code this is to use regular expressions. Code like below:

```
import re

if re.search("who\s.*are\s.*you","who the heck are you"):
    print("I AM JOE")
```

In the pattern `who\s.*are\s.*you`, `.*` means matching any string and `\s` means matching whitespaces.

Comment: Yuck Regex! who bare bayou would be print the message. I'm sure there is some awful tweak you can make to get regex to work, though

Comment: @FirebladeDan: you're right, edited the original post to include spaces.

Comment: This makes the words searched for static. Searching for words from a list would force you to generate the regex pattern

Comment: This now fails for `"who are you"` (pattern requires at least two spaces between the target words). Regex is not a good solution for this problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell just because the regex isn't written quite right doesn't mean its a bad tool. `re.search(r'\s.*'.join(w), "who are you")` works.

Comment: @tdelaney: And that has the same problem [that FirebladeDan pointed out in the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030518/test-for-multiple-strings-in-a-certain-order#comment55816818_34030617): it catches `"who bare bayou"`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell oops... time to deploy some positive lookback; `re.search(r'\s.*(?<=\s)'.join(w), "who bare bayou")`

Comment: Or, just pick up your screwdriver instead of trying to duct tape a phillips bit onto the hammer.

Answer (score 2):

This tests word-by-word, checking if each keyword is contained after the previous one.

```
def find_in_order(text, words):
    tokens = text.split()
    start = 0
    for word in words:
        try:
            start = tokens.index(word, start) + 1
        except:
            return False
    return True
```

tests:

```
>>> find_in_order("who the hell are you", ["who", "are", "you"])
True
>>> find_in_order("who the hell is you", ["who", "are", "you"])
False
>>> find_in_order("you who the hell are you", ["who", "are", "you"])
True
>>> find_in_order("who bare bayou", ["who", "are", "you"])
False
>>> find_in_order("who are you", ["who", "are", "are", "you"])
False
```

Or use a variation that does not split at spaces, and therefore `who bare byou` would pass:

```
def find_in_order(text, words):
    start = 0
    for word in words:
        try:
            start = text.index(word, start) + len(word)
        except:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can has a lot of scenarios, first of all you need to specify that the frequency of each word in your text, for example what if you have a sentence like following:

```
s = "you who the heck are you"
```

Any way if you suppose to that the words have repeated one time in your example sentence you can use `list.index` method and check if the indices are sorted then the order is like as the words list:

```
>>> s = "who the heck are you"
>>> 
>>> w = ["who", "are", "you"] 
>>> splitted_text = s.split()
>>> indices = [splitted_text.index(i) for i  in w]
>>> sorted(indices) == indices
True
```

Note that since `str.find()` search a pattern in whole of your string, it's not a proper choice for getting the index of words because you may have a word like `Areyou` which if you use `str.find` to find the index of word `you` it will returns the index of the start of the word till `you` is not a separate word.

Or if you want to use regex you can create your regex based on the order of your words using `str.join()` function:

```
>>> pattern = r'\b.*\b'.join(w)
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern)
>>>
>>> bool(regex.search(s))
True
>>> s = " you who the heck are"
>>> bool(regex.search(s))
False
```

Comment: It should perhaps be noted for the regex solution that `\b` matches _any_ transition from `\w` to `\W` (or vice versa), not just whitespace transitions, so that e.g., `"@who"` matches `\bwho`, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without using regex is using your original intuition to continually apply find on the same sentence in order. Here you would use the "reduce" function. It would look something like this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x[x.find(y):], ["who", "are", "you"], "who the heck are you")
```

This continually reduces the sentence by the list of search terms. The last value will be the remainder of the sentence if the last word exists, or the last character if they don't exist. So you could write a function like so:

```
def find_in_order(sentence, word_list):
  return reduce(lambda x, y: x[x.find(y):], word_list, sentence).startswith(word_list[-1])

>>> find_in_order('who the heck are you', ['who', 'are', 'you'])
True
```

There is one issue where if the last word is a single character which happens to be the last character of the sentence this would always return True. If that is an issue you can simply append something to the end of the sentence that does not match the last search item.

Comment: This also matches `who bare bayou`

Comment: The original question was to find multiple strings in a certain order, not multiple words separated by spaces or punctuation in a certain order. Being able to parse language is a very different question.